# How to re-Arrange and re-Measure a UserControl when it's removed from its parent?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, measure

I have a `Border` which contains a `UserControl` for previewing before printing.

Since the calculations done in this `UserControl` are quite time consuming, i'd like to print the instance that currently resides in the `Border`.

However, when I remove this `UserControl` from its parent (the Border), I can't seem to re-Arrange and re-Measure its dimensions.

The `UserControl` `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties are not affacted by the re-Arrange and re-Measue.

Here's how I do it:

```
XZReport rap = new XZReport();
xzPreview.Child = rap;

...

xzPreview.Child = null;
PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();

rap.Measure(new Size(dlg.PrintableAreaWidth, double.PositiveInfinity));
rap.Arrange(new Rect(rap.DesiredSize));
rap.UpdateLayout();
// setting a breakpoint here, I see ActualWidth and ActualHeight properties are not changed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by moving my calculations to a `ViewModel`, it then allowed me to use the first instance of my `ViewModel` without re-calculation everything, and allows me to create a new instance of my `View` without affecting the measurement of the dimensions for printing.